# Prolog-cut & fail

Tags: prolog, combinations

I have this function comb(2,[1,2,3],A) witch finds the combinations with the elements of a list. now i want to make a function witch puts me all these combinations in a list without sending `;` in command line:

```
 R=[[1, 2],[1, 3],[2, 3]]
```

instead of:

```
 A = [1, 2] ;
 A = [1, 3] ;
 A = [2, 3] ;
```

Answer (score 2):

`findall(A, comb(2, [1, 2, 3], A), R).`

Comment: ... or `bagof`, depending on how it is going to be used: `bagof` fails when there are no solution, while `findall` succeeds with an empty list.